# Histogram for a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to construct a histogram (or  empirical distribution function) for a dataframe column (=a column contatining a number of daily observations).
The dataframe column has the following structure (below)
Thanks in advance!

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.to_datetime(["2021-3-22", "2021-4-7", "2021-4-18", "2021-5-12","2022-3-22", "2022-4-7", "2022-4-18", "2022-5-12"]),
"x": [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3,4,2 ]})


date    x
0   2021-03-22  1
1   2021-04-07  1
2   2021-04-18  1
3   2021-05-12  3
4   2022-03-22  2
5   2022-04-07  3
6   2022-04-18  4
7   2022-05-12  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has plotting feature with matplotlib backend as default, so you can do it like this:

```py
df1.x.hist()
```

More: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pyplot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(df1.x)
#if you just want to look at the plot
plt.show()
#if you want to save the plot to a file
plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

Here's the documentation with all the options: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html.